# upate ListFragment from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

i am trying to reload ListFragment from AsyncTask like this :

```
    //set the string of the kitchen banner depending on the 
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
  super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    RequestNewTopBannerFragment requestNewTopBannerFragment = new RequestNewTopBannerFragment();
    Bundle argsBanner = new Bundle();
    argsBanner.putString(RequestNewTopBannerFragment.ARG_KEY_BANNER_TEXT_STR, crrentTopBannerString);//this.currentRequestType ContractFoodServices.NEW_REQUEST_CONST;
    requestNewTopBannerFragment.setArguments(argsBanner);


    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_top_banner_kitchen, requestNewTopBannerFragment) ;

    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();//LIGHT TIGER : commitAllowingStateLoss()
}
```

but although i am doing this in function "onProgressUpdate" but i have get exception "IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"
of course if i change the function "commit" to "commitAllowingStateLoss" it shows the same exception , and at the same time , the Fragment is not reloaded all the times , some times it works and others not.

i tried to use another way to reload the ListFragment  from thread so i tried this code :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 public void run()   {

                RequestNewTopBannerFragment requestNewTopBannerFragment = new RequestNewTopBannerFragment();
    Bundle argsBanner = new Bundle();
    argsBanner.putString(RequestNewTopBannerFragment.ARG_KEY_BANNER_TEXT_STR, crrentTopBannerString);//this.currentRequestType ContractFoodServices.NEW_REQUEST_CONST;
    requestNewTopBannerFragment.setArguments(argsBanner);


    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_top_banner_kitchen, requestNewTopBannerFragment) ;

    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();//LIGHT TIGER : commitAllowingStateLoss() 
                }
        });
```

but it did not work too , and show the same exception , so what is the solution to be able to reload the FragmentList at all time from "AsyncTask"

thanks in advance

Comment: try to update RequestNewTopBannerFragment's content instead of create a new fragment

Comment: See this [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) about this topic for more information.

Comment: What is your goal? Doing a transaction an every `onProgressUpdate`?? What for?